# Matlab / Java Linked List Error need a solution

Tags: matlab, linked-list

i'm working on my Final university Project , and my time is too short 
the project is about Wireless sensor network and i have to simulate one of the recent papers about it.
most of the coding is done but i have a simple problem about linked list(i use matlab and import java libraries into it for using linked list)

okay 
here is some explanation 
i have a queue/list that every time head of the list is checked that is it the goal or not 
if its not a goal it deletes the first item and gets the second one which is actualy the first one in the list 
problem occurs when my list has only 1 item and its not goal so code delete the first item , AFTER that 
code tries to get the first item which is null and empty thats when Error happens ,

my goal is after checking/searching all the list if it was successful turn flagg=1 if not flagg=0

```
while temp ~= goal;

    for K=1:size(G,1)

     if temp == G(K,1)
         q.add(G(K,2))

     end
    end

     if (~q.isEmpty())

       q.removeFirst();
       temp=q.getFirst(); 

     else
         flagg=1

     end

end
```

Thanks.
M.Dadmand